# Why is deadlock in this code detected?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I learned shared lock, which blocks exlcusive lock. When an insert statement with a foreign key is executed, the parent record is by shared locked.
But in the code below, the slock doesn't seem to block the xlock. so why does deadlock occurs?

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
mysql -u root test <<EOS
drop table if exists child;
create table child (id int, pid int, primary key (id, pid))engine=innodb;

drop table if exists parent;
create table parent (id int, count int, primary key (id))engine=innodb;
insert into parent values (1, 0);

alter table child add foreign key (pid) references parent (id);
EOS

q1=$(cat<<EOS
begin;
insert into child values (1, 1);  -- slock parent(id=1)
select sleep(1);
update parent set count = count + 1 where id = 1;  -- xlock(parent(id=1))
commit;
EOS
)

q2=$(<<EOS
begin;
update parent set count = count + 1 where id = 1;  -- xlock(parent(id=1))
select sleep(1);
commit;
EOS
)

mysql -u root test <<< "$q1" &
mysql -u root test <<< "$q2" &
wait
mysql -u root test -e 'select * from child;'
mysql -u root test -e 'select * from parent;
```

Comment: Could you include the error output?

Comment: This is the error message.
ERROR 1213 (40001) at line 2: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Comment: this code doesn't work:( sorry